# NSURLComponent is not giving right URL when IP address exist in URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, nsurlcomponents

My NSURLComponents is translating '/' to '%2F'. Please see log after 10.32.135.10.

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponent = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
[urlComponent setScheme:@"http"];
[urlComponent setHost:@"10.32.135.10/test.API"];
[urlComponent setPath:@"/api/path"];
urlComponent.queryItems = qItems;
```

In Log when I executed

```
po [urlComponent URL]
http://10.32.135.10%2Ftest.API/api/path?asetTypeId=1003
```

Why backward slash is translated into %2F.
Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `/test.API` should be on the `path`.

Let's think about it the other way:

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://10.32.135.10/test.API/api/path?asetTypeId=1003";
NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
NSLog(@"Host: %@", [components host]);
NSLog(@"Path: %@", [components path]);
NSLog(@"QueryItems: %@", [components queryItems]);
```

Output:

```
$>Host: 10.32.135.10
$>Path: /test.API/api/path
$>QueryItems: (
    "<NSURLQueryItem 0x600000254760> {name = asetTypeId, value = 1003}"
)
```

Fix:

```
[urlComponent setHost:@"10.32.135.10"];
[urlComponent setPath:@"/test.API/api/path"];
```

Comment: Amazing, starting analysis from the other side is really amazing.